# How to get Netlogo model automatically stop, close file and start the model again

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing the disease spreading model and it took a long time to process my model.

I want after the model stopped, and then `close-file`, `setup` (In my `setup` process, It has to write the new file before) and then `go` again.

How could I code the loop like this? or if it's impossible for Netlogo, feel free to comment down here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are trying to do multiple runs of the model, it is much easier to use the BehaviorSpace tool. Also, how many agents do you have in your model?

Comment: I got 1000 agents in my model, I'm still validating my model but I have to keep an eye on my computer all the time hahaha.

Comment: Adding to the comment of @JenB, you should use BehaviorSpace and let it write the output for you.  If you additionally need run-specific files to be output, you can use `behaviorspace-run-number` to create a separate filename for each run. However, this is often unnecessary.

Comment: If you only have 1000 agents, I am concerned that you think it takes a long time to run. That should be very quick even if you are running for thousands of ticks. You might want to check for nested `ask`.

Comment: @Alan Thank you very much, I know how to use BehaviorSpace already!

Comment: @JenB Actually, I'm still curious that why only 1000 agents or even I run only 500 agents, it took a very long time, about an hour or more than that sometimes. What nested  `ask` mean? It's mean I have many `ask` during my process, isn't it?

Comment: 1000 agents taking an hour to run means there is something very badly wrong with your code. Nested `ask` means that you have a procedure that `ask turtles` something and that something also `ask turtles` for example. Start a new question, or use the profiler extension.

Comment: @JenB I'm not sure what each agent is doing and if there's any computationally expensive tasks that are running. Adrian, can you post your code?

Comment: @JenB Thank you so much, I did do the nested `ask` and after I solve this, my model run much faster :)))